# Mixed content: Chrome blocking <img> at my site but not

Tags: html, mixed-content

I have an HTTPS site that loads contents from an HTTP RSS feed. When trying to load the images, Chrome/Firefox blocks them with this message:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'mysite.com/index.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.example.com/2017021411050.jpg'. This request has been blocked; **the content must be served over HTTPS**.
```

However, if I load the same feed in Feeldy, I can see all the images despite Feedly's site is also loaded through HTTPS. In the Feedly case, the browser shows just a warning:

```
The page at 'https://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/http://www.example.com/rss.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.example.com/2017021411050.jpg'. **This content should also be served over HTTPS**.
```

Why Feedly can bypass the mixed-content block and is getting just a warning while I'am getting a block?

Comment: Hi, did you find a reason for the warning versus error difference?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and chrome are both secure browsers but I'm not sure what Feedly exactly is.
Firefox and chrome block them because they think it's not secure to load a HTTP image in a HTTP website but Feedly doesn't care so he thinks just giving a warning is enough.
But I know a solution to fix this
for example you got this URL

```
http://otherdomain.com/image.jpg
```

which is a HTTP , then you change it like

```
https://example.com/imageserver?url= //here put your image url
```

this trick will make the browser think you are loading the image over a HTTPS URL like below

```
https://example.com/imageserver?url=http://otherdomain.com/image.jpg&hash=abcdeafad
```

Comment: I know how MC and browsers work, but the key is why Feedly (an online RSS reader, so, a web app like mine) is able to get the HTTP images with just a waning while for the same image I am getting a block. What technique do they use to bypasss the blocking?

Comment: This is literally a copy paste of my answer lmao

Comment: oh melvin Koopmans I'm new to this stackoverflow , and I guess we post the same answer at the same time because at the time I was answering to this question there was no other answer so I apologize for duplicated answer

Answer (score -1):

When parsing the RSS feed you're also retrieving the image urls.

Lets say the image url is http://externalsite.com/someimage.jpg.

You rewrite this URL as https://example.com/image?url=http://externalsite.com/someimage.jpg&hash=1234567.

Now the browser always makes the request over https, and you get rid of the problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not asking that. The question is about Feedly's techniques to bypass the MC block. Feedly doesn't seem to act like a proxy for the images.

Comment: @AitorF So the src of the images is http://, and it doesn't give any mixed content errors when loading with HTTPS??

Comment: Right! In Feedly, but in my case I get a big red error.